# Is it a good idea to register style only in certain WP pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagespeed

I have a page speed issue, the theme I bought is really crappy but i cannot change it now. I use WP_rocket, server have HTTP2 but still it is to many resources to load. So i try to reduce numbers of styles by wp_deregister_style and load it only when need. For example contact-form-7 front-end style I need only in .../contact page. It good idea ? Or it could be harmful?

function rs_deregister_css () {

```
global $wp;
 $url = home_url( $wp->request);
 $contakt = strpos($url,'contakt');

   if (!$contakt) {
        wp_deregister_style('contact-form-7');
  }
```

}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'rs_deregister_css', 99);

Comment: Yes, its a very good idea, don't forget to deregister the javascript file, too ( `wp_deregister_script('contact-form-7');`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its a very good idea since you only use the contact form in the contact page, don't forget to deregister the javascript file, too

```
if (!$contakt) {
  wp_deregister_style('contact-form-7');
  wp_deregister_script('contact-form-7');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be a good idea for your load time. But I suggest you to load style on specific instead of checking the URL and unload it every time.

Try to read [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

```
function my_enqueue_stuff() {
  if ( is_front_page() ) {
    /** Call landing-page-template-one enqueue */
        wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/yourfile.css' );
  } else {
    /** Call regular enqueue */
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_stuff' );
```

EDIT

Since you only want to the style or javascript load for specific pages, then add this code to your functions.php:

```
function remove_wpcf7_extras() {
    remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpcf7_enqueue_styles');
}

if( !is_page('contact') ) {
    add_action('wp_head', 'remove_wpcf7_extras');
}
```

Comment: `is_front_page` should be `is_front_page()`.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't write that. Thanks!

Comment: The problem from this solution is that If you don't prevent loading CSS, the plugin will load it by its own. So the code provided in the question looks like a better solution

Comment: Then it only needs to add his code to prevent it, because it more efficient than checking the URL every time. I Update my answer.